# Mysql return 0 not null in sum

Tags: mysql, null, aggregate-functions

Help needed please I have a table with taskId, Materials, Labour and a table with expenses in. The issue i have is that some tasks do not have and expense column in the taskenpense table so the column returns null. I need null to be 0.

```
       ` CREATE TABLE emptasks (  empTaskId INT,  taskMaterials NUMERIC(8,2),taskLabour NUMERIC(8,2));
        INSERT INTO emptasks VALUES
      (1,  50, 50),
      (2,   450.26, 50),
      (3,  2505.10, 50),
       (4, 2505.10, 50),
       (5, 500, 500),
       (6, 1000, 50);


    CREATE TABLE taskexpenses (
      feeID INT,
      empTaskId INT,
      expense NUMERIC(8,2));

    INSERT INTO taskexpenses VALUES
    (1, 1,  50.00),
      (1, 2,  50.00),
      (2, 2, 126.00),
      (3, 3,  50.00),
      (4, 4,  50.00),
      (2, 2, 1206.00);

SELECT
    p.empTaskId,
      p.Labour,
      p.Materials,
      f.Expenses,
      p.Labour + p.Materials - f.Expenses AS Total,
   ROUND( (f.Expenses  + p.Materials) / p.Labour * 100, 2) AS Percentage
    FROM (
      SELECT
      empTaskId, 
        SUM(taskMaterials) AS Labour,
      SUM(taskLabour) AS Materials
      FROM emptasks
      GROUP BY empTaskId
    ) p
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT taskexpenses.empTaskId,

      SUM(expense) AS Expenses
      FROM emptasks
      INNER JOIN taskexpenses ON emptasks.empTaskId = taskexpenses.empTaskId
      GROUP BY empTaskId
    ) f ON p.empTaskId = f.empTaskId

the result is
empTaskId   Labour  Materials   Expenses    Total   Percentage
1            50        50        50          50      200
2          450.26      50       1382        -881.74 318.04
3          2505.1      50       50          2505.1  3.99
4          2505.1      50       50          2505.1  3.99
5           500         500    (null)      (null)   (null)
6          1000        50      (null)      (null)   (null)
```

I need the  null value to return 0 so the sum can be worked out
 [FIDDLE LINK](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32182/1)
THanks
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly simpler than in the answer from @Bob Jarvis is to use the `IFNULL()` function.

```
SELECT
    p.empTaskId,
      p.Labour,
      p.Materials,
      IFNULL(f.Expenses, '0') AS Expenses,
      IFNULL(p.Labour + p.Materials - f.Expenses, '0') AS Total,
   IFNULL(ROUND( (f.Expenses  + p.Materials) / p.Labour * 100, 2), '0') AS Percentage
    FROM ...
```

See [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32182/10)

Comment: In line 6 above, zero will be returned if `Labour` and `Materials` are non-NULL but `Expenses` is NULL (because non-NULL + non-NULL - NULL is NULL).

Comment: That's an unlikely scenario @Bob Jarvis. Either Expenses, Total and Percentage are all NULL because the LEFT JOIN didn't find a row to join, or all numbers.

Comment: @marekful Hi thanks for your answer but the query does not work check your fiddle example the  total on id 5 and 6 should not be zero 5 should be total 1000 and  6 should be total 1500  `IFNULL(p.Labour + p.Materials - f.Expenses, '0') AS Total,`  labour + material - expenses = total Any ideas Thank Jon

Comment: OK, since the `taskexpenses` table may not have a corresponding row for `emptasks` the `IFNULL` function calls needed to be rearranged so they're applied to `f.Expenses` instead of the result of the full calculations. New [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32182/15)

Comment: @marekful How would i had a third table with flueid, empId, taskId, Miles , cost. Could you fiddle it for me LOL I would like to keep flue expenses in another table but still work it into the query thanks for your help cheers Jon

Comment: @marekful OK think i have sorted it can you take a look for me I am a newbie  [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d62fe/3) IS this OK thanks again for your help

Comment: @marekful this is great was looking for this exact solution; in my case I have SUM(...) which might result in a NULL value and I wanted 0 returned in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the COALESCE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html):

```
SELECT p.empTaskId,
       p.Labour,
       p.Materials,
       COALESCE(f.Expenses, 0) AS Expenses,
       COALESCE(p.Labour, 0) + COALESCE(p.Materials, 0) - COALESCE(f.Expenses, 0) AS Total,
      ROUND( (COALESCE(f.Expenses, 0) + COALESCE(p.Materials, 0)) / p.Labour * 100, 2) AS Percentage
  FROM (SELECT empTaskId, 
               SUM(COALESCE(taskMaterials, 0)) AS Labour,
               SUM(COALESCE(taskLabour, 0)) AS Materials
          FROM emptasks
          GROUP BY empTaskId) p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT taskexpenses.empTaskId,
                    SUM(COALESCE(expense, 0)) AS Expenses
               FROM emptasks
               INNER JOIN taskexpenses
                 ON emptasks.empTaskId = taskexpenses.empTaskId
               GROUP BY empTaskId) f
    ON p.empTaskId = f.empTaskId
```

Note that here I've put COALESCE on just about everything which might possibly be NULL. If you only want to put it on the `Expenses` column change it to be what you want.

Best of luck.